# "No resource methods" when using JAX-RS on TomEE+

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-rs, apache-tomee

Using stock TomEE+, I cannot get a simple JAX-RS resource to work.  I constantly get an error of:

```
Jun 30, 2012 5:09:59 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ResourceUtils checkMethodDispatcher
WARNING: No resource methods have been found for resource class com.tensorwrench.test.BaseResource
Jun 30, 2012 5:09:59 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ResourceUtils checkMethodDispatcher
WARNING: No resource methods have been found for resource class com.tensorwrench.test.BaseResource
Jun 30, 2012 5:09:59 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ResourceUtils checkMethodDispatcher
WARNING: No resource methods have been found for resource class com.tensorwrench.test.BaseResource
Jun 30, 2012 5:09:59 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean checkResources 
SEVERE: No resource classes found
Jun 30, 2012 5:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive D:\workspace\api\src\main\catalina_base\webapps\testapi-1.0.war
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:194)
                at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deploy(CxfRsHttpListener.java:126)
                at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployPojo(CxfRsHttpListener.java:97)
                at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.deployPojo(RESTService.java:270)
                at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:173)
                at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxRsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxRsService.java:55)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.WebDeploymentListeners.afterApplicationCreated(WebDeploymentListeners.java:38)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.afterStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:818)
                at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:103)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:168)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1603)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.checkResources(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:312)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:144)
                ... 23 more
```

Resource class:
    package com.tensorwrench.test;

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/test")
public class BaseResource {
  @GET @Produces("text/plain") @Path("test") Response helloWorld() {
    return Response.ok("Hello world","plain/text").build();
  }
  @GET @Produces("text/plain") String helloWorld2() {
    return "Hello world without path!";
  }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="api" version="3.0" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>Service</display-name>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.apache.openejb:javaee-api:6.0-4'
}

version = '1.0'
jar {
        manifest {
                attributes 'Title': 'Services',
                                     'Version': version
        }
}

</web-app>
```

I've tried a number of permutations, adding beans.xml, removing, changing order of the annotations, using different compile dependencies for the Java EE classes.  I consistently get this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your resource methods are not `public` in scope.  Try this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
@Path("/test")
public class BaseResource {
  @GET @Produces("text/plain") @Path("test") public Response helloWorld() {
    return Response.ok("Hello world","plain/text").build();
  }
  @GET @Produces("text/plain") public String helloWorld2() {
    return "Hello world without path!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  Always the easy thing that's the hardest to see. :/

Comment: No worries, we like to try and catch [stuff like that](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-453), but currently that code is mostly around EJB.  Added a JIRA for this one https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-260